# Is it HTML5 App or Android Native App?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, html, swift

How can I know if any certain application was developed using HTML5 or it's a native app (i.e. Android native app or iOs native app)?

As an example, Is twitter a native app or HTML5 based app?

My question is general, I just give the above question as an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look here then check the real app in mobile about its performance. then you'll find that

Native apps are :

1. Faster load times compared to web apps
2. Robust performance in online or offline mode
3. Rich UI and smooth, engaging user experience
4. Better discoverability and brand image
5. Require development for each mobile platform
6. Native development skills are expensive!

In HTML5 based apps:

1. All the UX/performance issues outlined above will still apply. As these apps require consistent internet connection, they limit the users’ capability to utilize them in low/no bandwidth areas.
2. These apps will be built with the exact same function for every device; with no unique functions that users have come to expect in a mobile experience.

**If want to check some more then you can unzip the .apk with any tool like winzip or winrar. If it's an html5-based app, you will see .html, .js and .css files in the /res/assets folder. otherwise Native**

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Hi It is really a confusing question to determine as a user, whether app is 
Html 5 or Native(Android).

Once i got to judge one app. I done following Scenarios to judge the app.

- Performance of the app
- Install Proxy debugger like **httpScoop** or **charles proxy** and set your device through internet desktop, where proxies are being installed. Now browse the app and see its functionalities. As your are using app. You will get many logs in your Proxy debugger.
- Check the proxy logs carefully if it is hybrid (html5). you will get many .js files. Based on that you can judge your app. It would be not in all cases.